# Multiiplication in two different Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, math

i have use the following code snippet in my working scenorio  of JavaScript.

```
var t = 0.000029411764705882354 * 34000;
```

the result of t is 1 . i want to get the exact multiplication result instead of 1 as

0.9999999999972.

Comment: Some helpful links!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken , 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html , http://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php?db=comics&id=2999#comic

Comment: You can't get exact results because every number in JavaScript is a 64-bit float. `0.000029411764705882354` cannot be represented exactly in base-2. You will have to represent them in decimal using some library.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem

Answer (score 2):

First up, that *doesn't* evaluate to 1. The expression:

```
29411764705882354 * 34
```

(removing multiplication by powers of ten) actually gives you:

```
1000000000000000036
```

On top of that, unless you have infinite storage capabilities, no encoding scheme can represent every single number. You'll need to get used to the fact that floating point is, more often than not, an approximation of what you asked for - some numbers can be represented exactly but, in the domain of all reals, they form a vanishingly small section :-)

Having said that, there's a couple of ways around it.

First, you can use a bignum-type library (such as MPIR in C) to give you arbitrary (NOT infinite) precision arithmetic. This will handle most cases okay other than irrationals.

Second, you can continue to use floating point but be aware it's not exact and you may need to print out *rounded* numbers. For example, `0.9999999999972` rounded to <=11 decimal (NOT significant) digits gives you `1`.